# Nested Serializer in Django Rest Framework API

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am using the Rest Framework in Django. I use the  browsable API feature to auto-generate forms (for http POST,PUT etc) based on the Serializer for the  given API.

My problem is that I am now creating an API with a nested serializer to receive a list of dictionaries in a known format. The declaration of the the nested serializer within the main serializer is:

```
customer_hosts = CustomerNetworkHostSerializer(many=True, required=True)
```

My API inherits generic's CreateAPIView form rest_framework. I also set the serializer_class to my main serializer.

The API works fine with the serializer if I manually send the required json object using a http post but I have no way to send the values for that variable using a browser with the auto-generated form. The variable with the nested serializer does not show up at all.

So what I am looking for is away to get the browsable_api working with a nested dynamic serializer if is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the exact RFC reference but the limitation here is HTTP.
HTTP forms cannot natively encode nested data structures (both application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data rely on flat key-value formats)

one approach here might be to create a page that uses the browsableapi renderer to render those parts of your form that are possible and then implement your own logic to
- render the nested serializer
- format the form and contents into other language for submission to your end point (e.g. convert the html form and contents to json: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery))